# How to FGREP 2 dashes '--'?

Tags: linux, grep

`fgrep -ircl --include=*.{sql} "[--]" *` doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Please help...

Thanks for the responses guys. I am trying to replace the '--' with '#' and am having a tough time. I created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740845/help-with-perl-regex-recursive-replace-one-liner-replace-mysql-comments-wit) here. If you could help, that had be awesome.

Comment: I agree and disagree. It performs good so far, better than grep..

And fgrep stands for fast-grep too!

Comment: No, it does not. It's a popular fallacy that `fgrep' stands for fast-grep. In fact `fgrep' means fixed-string grep, it has no performance boost over `grep'. http://ss64.com/bash/fgrep.html (or >man fgrep)

Comment: @meagar yes it is. "fgrep is a faster version of grep which does not support regular expressions and therefore is considered to be faster." http://www.linuxconfig.org/Grep_egrep_fgrep_rgrep#3-4-fgrep

Comment: We are now off topic... OP should change title to FGREP!

Comment: Changed but I see conflicting info on fgrep. I like it though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fgrep all files that end with `.sql` then use

```
fgrep -ircl --include=*.sql -- -- *
```

or (note the comma in `{sql,}`:

```
fgrep -ircl --include=*.{sql,} -- -- *
```

If you want to fgrep more than one type of extension, then use something like

```
fgrep -ircl --include=*.{sql,txt} -- -- *
```

As others have already mentioned, the first `--` tells fgrep to stop looking for flags and options. The second `--` is the fixed-string pattern.

Answer (score 4):

That looks like a regular expression character class matching the (single) `-` character. The string `--` is commonly used to indicate "no more parameters follow", so perhaps you should try

```
fgrep -ircl --include=*.{sql} -- -- *
```

that is "end of parameters" followed by the actual string you want to search for.

Comment: Strangely enough, it works without --include=*.{sql} .. any ideas?

Comment: @NJTechie If you omit the `--include`, then all files/sub-directories in the current directory will be searched, as you're passing them as arguments. That's what the final `*` does - matches all files in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape dash characters inside square brackets, which are used to represent ranges inside a character class (`[a-z]` for example).  In this case, however, you don't need to use square brackets to match a literal string.

Finally, `--` is a speical sequence that causes [argument parsing](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long) to stop.  To include a literal `--` as an argument, you'll have to explicitly stop argument parsing:

```
fgrep -ircl --include=*.{sql} -- -- *
```

Comment: Escaping inside a character class isn't going to change the meaning, though.

Answer (score 1):

Dash characters can only be in the first position in brackets [] because they indicate a range [a-z] or [0-9]. You could do [-][-].

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes `'[--]'` instead of `"[--]"`

```
fgrep -ircl --include=*.{sql} '[--]' *
```