# How can I convert SQL comments with -- to # using Perl?

Tags: sql, regex, perl

UPDATE:

This is what works!

```
fgrep -ircl --include=*.sql -- -- *
```

I have various SQL files with '--' comments and we migrated to the latest version of MySQL and it hates these comments. I want to replace -- with #.

I am looking for a recursive, inplace replace one-liner.

This is what I have:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/--/# /g'` ``fgrep -- -- *
```

A sample .sql file:

```
use myDB;

--did you get an error
```

I get the following error:

> Unrecognized switch: --did  (-h will show valid options).

p.s : fgrep skipping 2 dashes was just [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740599/how-to-fgrep-2-dashes) if you are interested.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command-line arguments after the `-e 's/.../.../'`  argument should be filenames. Use `fgrep -l` to return names of files that contain a pattern:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/--/# /g' `fgrep -l -- -- * `
```

Comment: This works great but the only problem I see is that if the folders have a space (ex. SQL Scripts), then it fails. Not sure how to deal with that and one other problem (less critical) is that it is diving deep into tar files and trying to replace and is failing too. Thought? Thank you..

Comment: Maybe an `xargs` solution? I'm not proficient with that tool, but something like `fgrep -l -- -- * | xargs perl -p -i -e '...'` might do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a combination of `find` and inplace `sed`

```
find . -name '*.sql' -exec sed -i -e "s/^--/#/" '{}' \;
```

---

Note that it will only replace lines **beginning** with `--`
The regex will become vastly more complex if you wan't to replace this for example:

```
INSERT INTO stuff VALUES (...) -- values used for xyz
```

because the `--` might as well be in your data (I guess you don't want to replace those)

```
INSERT INTO stuff VALUES (42, "<!-- sboing -->") -- values used for xyz
```

Comment: This is the right answer. Using Perl for this problem is overkill when there are excellent command-line utilities that will do the same for you with less fuss.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense too. Thank you.

Comment: I prefer this answer for a one-liner, as it gets round the spaces-in-filenames problem by using find's --exec. Also, '--' at the beginning of the line is an important point.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of that in script form is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -i
use warnings;
use strict;

while(<>) {
    s/--/# /g;
    print;

}
```

If I have several files with comments of the form of `--comment` and feed any number of names to this script, they are changed in place to `# comment` You could use find, ls, grep, etc to find the files...

There is nothing per se wrong with using a 1 liner.

Is that what you are looking for?